# Why is the declared type different from the instantiated type?

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrenthashmap

final Map map =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Why declare a Map and instantiate a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: you may want to google "code against interfaces". The explanation is way too broad to explain here

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/6253321